# maven: export meta of all dependencies when package a fatjar

Tags: maven, dependencies

A project maintained by a team, will be build to a fat jar, all dependencies will be package in.

When the project is continuous integration, dependencies will add, remove or update.

So is there a maven plugins or runtime dependencies analysis tool can collect/upload/print the dependencies' meta in an analyzable and comparable data-format. So I can analysis and compare two CI version difference.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using maven dependency plugin during the build.
It can analyze the pom.xml and some goals allow printing dependencies in a textual form that can be compared later.

Namely check the option of:

```
mvn dependency:tree

mvn dependency:list
```